# What are the different ways of STDIN in java

Tags: java, stdin

I was thinking on `STDIN`. `System.in` is standard stream for `STDIN` in Java. For general propose, keyboard is used to provide input to `STDIN` but if the input is large contains too many parameters, then typing every parameter using keyboard is quite difficult and impossible too.
What can be any alternative for the same scenario?

Comment: Where are these parameters coming from? Are they in a file, on the internet, or in you mind? I suggest you read the parameters from where they are currently.

Comment: Command line parameters and standard in are not the same thing.  If your input has to be large, store it in a file and pipe it into your program via input redirection.  All major shells support this, including all linux ones and the windows command prompt.  Use `java [args] [class] [program args] < inputfile.txt`

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Good question. I was thinking on the process of providing input on the answers in online programming sites. Take an example, you have submitted java code to server, which takes input from `STDIN` using `System.in`, how server is going to provide inputs that java code?

Comment: @Wug:Take an example to understand the question exactly. You have submitted Java code to server, which takes input from `STDIN` using `System.in`, how server is going to provide inputs that Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how server is going to provide inputs that Java code?

Usually you would have a number of canned inputs as files.  So you would run

```
java -cp build-dir ClassName < input-N.txt > build-dir/output-N.txt 2>&1
```

Then you would compare your output-N.txt with the one generated by the program to see if its close enough.

This will pass all the contents of the file to System.in and write all the output to System.out and System.err to the output file.

Comment: Is it same as reading values from file `input-N.txt` using `FileReader` or any appropriate Java API?

Comment: Thank you Peter. Let me try this. Will let you know if any thing wrong happen.

Comment: It is exactly the same as using FileInputStream on the file.

Comment: One last question. In your answer, you have written build-`dir/output-N.txt 2>&1` . Why last argument i.e. `2>&1` is used? Can you explain the whole command?

Comment: It combines System.err with System.out. If the program has a runtime error, like a stack trace, you will record it in one file.  Its better than showing them a file which is empty or just stops.

Comment: I am unable to run the command. Can you please give me an example for the same command.

Comment: To run a shell command from Java you need to use a shell like Runtime.exec("sh -c 'java -cp build-dir ClassName < input-N.txt > build-dir/output-N.txt 2>&1'") and you should read the getErrorStream() to check for errors.